# Phoenix 1.2 start page loads blank

Tags: http-status-code-404, phoenix-framework

When I generate a new Phoenix application, start the server and go to `localhost:4000`, I just see a blank page.

It also prints out a `Failed to load resource` error for `favicon.ico` in the javascript console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the browser cookies for `localhost:4000` resolved this error for me.